# Customize Left hand navigation in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

How to customize the left hand navigation in sharepoint.  [Check this site](http://www.anderson.ucla.edu/x27476.xml), in this site if you see the left hand navigation opens and collapses, by clicking on a link(say MBA financing) you will see some other links will be appeared. To do the similar, how to do this in Sharpeoint 2007.

Regards,
Abhimanyu

Comment: The question title also sounds like this, which I was actually looking for, i.e. just adding or removing items from the list without coding: http://office.microsoft.com/en-za/sharepoint-server-help/configure-navigation-items-on-the-site-navigation-settings-page-HA010118190.aspx

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN blog - Custom Navigation in SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/modonovan/custom-navigation-in-sharepoint-the-full-monty)

[MSDN blog - How to create custom navigation menu in SharePoint with XML data source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/matjazperpar/how-to-create-custom-navigation-menu-in-sharepoint-with-xml-data-source)

Comment: Can we do dynamically. I mean in that custom navigation, is it possible to show list items in a sharepoint list???

Comment: Yes!!! Maybe you should make your questions and requirements a little more detailed to begin with??? For example are you using 2007 or 2010 - there is a big difference in how to get the data out of the list.

Comment: ok. I edited my post, between i want to get data from the list in sharepoint 2007

Answer (score 1):

When ever such scenrios arise normally i would like to go for custom menu either by inhertting the ASP Site menu or using custom list view

Answer (score 1):

We used [this script](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=482) for a customer, not exactly what you need, but pretty close, it is jQuery

Answer (score 0):

This solution will utilize their built in navigation features, it pulls the menu data from sharepoint once they are entered in from the settings.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/